# permission Denied whil installing activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, permission-denied

I am trying to use activeadmin in my Rails app.But when i try to install activeadmin it throws 'permission denied' error.
I have added in my Gemfile.

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

When I run 'rails generate active_admin:install'
I get the following error

```
**/home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:101:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/cbls-2/academics/office_management/config/routes.rb (Errno::EACCES)**
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:101:in `open'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:101:in `replace!'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:59:in `invoke!'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:30:in `insert_into_file'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb:224:in `block in route'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:194:in `block in in_root'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:184:in `block in inside'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:128:in `chdir'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:128:in `cd'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:184:in `inside'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:194:in `in_root'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb:223:in `route'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.1.0/lib/generators/devise/devise_generator.rb:22:in `add_devise_routes'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:115:in `invoke'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-70cfbf3d7d33/lib/generators/active_admin/devise/devise_generator.rb:39:in `create_admin_user'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:115:in `invoke'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:277:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:68:in `with_padding'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:266:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:133:in `_invoke_from_option_users'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:130:in `generate_or_destroy'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/cbls-2/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:9:in `require'
from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try using 

gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

Comment: Already its like that. Please read the error message and try to find out the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo chown -R youruser ~/.rbenv
```

Comment: Tried this. But no help.